# Вопросительные знаки всместо русских букв

Tags: python, atom

Добрый Вечер.
Решил, значит, начать изучать Python.
Все как положено, установил интерпретатор, добавил в PATH, зашел в Atom, поставил пакет script. Написал код из одной строчки:

```
print("Привет, мир!")
```

Но вот не задача, в результате я получил вопросительные знаки вместо заветной фразы. 
Я сталкивался с чем-то подобным в С++ и снова в том же Atom.

Что могло послужить этому и возможно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь это в начало твоего скрипта:
`# coding: utf8`
Она изменит твою кодировку и русский язык начнет отображаться нормально.

Comment: Чет не очень.
Теперь выводит в консоли:
NameError: name 'utf8' is not defined

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  попробуй, у тебя кодировки не сходятся